# Add different shipping cost for different products using attributes(without extension)

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I tried to add different shipping costs for different products using http://blog.aajit.com/product-level-shipping-in-magento/ but i am getting 0 rs as flat rate in checkout. I should get different flat rate for different products how can do it?

**Flatrate.php**

```
class Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate
extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{

protected $_code = 'flatrate';
protected $_isFixed = true;

/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @param Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $data
 * @return Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result
 */
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    $freeBoxes = 0;
    if ($request->getAllItems()) {
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {

            if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }

            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                        $freeBoxes += $item->getQty() * $child->getQty();
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                $freeBoxes += $item->getQty();
            }
        }
    }
    $this->setFreeBoxes($freeBoxes);

    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    if ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'O') { // per order
        $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
    } elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'I') { // per item
        $shippingPrice = ($request->getPackageQty() * $this->getConfigData('price')) - ($this->getFreeBoxes() * $this->getConfigData('price'));
    } else {
        $shippingPrice = false;
    }

    $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($shippingPrice);
    $shippingPrice = $this->get_pro_ship();

    if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

        $method->setCarrier('flatrate');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('flatrate');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $this->getFreeBoxes()) {
            $shippingPrice = '0.00';
        }


        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

        $result->append($method);
    }

    return $result;
}

public function getAllowedMethods()
{
    return array('flatrate'=>$this->getConfigData('name'));
}

public function get_pro_ship()
{
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$cart_items = $session->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
$custom_ship=0;
foreach( $cart_items as $items ){

         $cur_fproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($items->getProductId());
    //$cur_fproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($items->getProduct_id());
$custom_ship +=($items->getQty())*($_helper->productAttribute($cur_fproduct, $cur_fproduct->getShippingWorld(), 'shipping_world'));                        
}


return $custom_ship ;   

}// function end
```

}

Comment: try this Extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flat-rate-shipping-per-product-6.html

Comment: i want to try it without extension

Comment: Use and extension for it! Every other way does not really make sense. Everything else would be an overwriting within the local files. That makes sense for small changes but not for a whole set of functions (what your requrement is).

Answer (score 2):

You need to create observer for it.
Step 1 :- put this code in your `app/code/local/Shipping/Disable/etc/config.xml` file.

```
<config>
  <frontend>
    <events>
      <sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
          <observers>
              <shipping_disable>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>disable/observer</class>
                  <method>salesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore</method>
              </shipping_disable>
          </observers>
      </sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
    </events>
  </frontend>
 </config>
```

Step-2 : Put this code in `app/code/local/Shipping/Disable/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Shipping_Disable_Model_Observer
{
 public function salesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote 778.78*/
            $quote = $observer->getQuote();
            $subTotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
            $newSubTotal = 55;  //update your price here 
            $store    = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
            $productAttr = array();
            foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $quote_item) {
                $productAttr[] = $quote_item->getYourProductCustomAttr();
        }
        if(is_array($productAttr) && count($productAttr > 0){
           $carriers = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers',$store);
           foreach ($carriers as $carrierCode => $carrierConfig) {
            if($carrierCode == 'fedex'){                      
                    $store->setConfig("carriers/freightquote/handling_fee", $newSubTotal);

            }

            }

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Note that this updates a configuration value. As such, it won't be visible unless you clear configuration cache. That is not something you want to do in the frontend, even though I know several extensions who do just that to update their license information - cache management is a backend's responsibility.